# How to get user interests from facebook using facebook sdk for android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am using facebook sdk in my app and fetching details like facebook_id, dob, email_id, user name etc. I am getting all these details and using them in my app but the thing is that now I want to fetch interests of the logged in user but I am not getting the same, don't know what is happening.

My code for fetching all these details is as follows :-

```
Session.openActiveSession(context, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

                @Override
                public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(session.isOpened())
                    {
                        showToast("Please wait");
                        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();

                        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                            pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
                            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(context, PERMISSIONS);
                            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                        }

                        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                if(user!=null)
                                {

                                    try{
                                        Log.d("", "Fb responcse == "+response.toString());
                                        Log.d("", "FbUser >> "+ user.toString());
                                        fbUserid=user.getId();
                                        fbAccessToken=session.getAccessToken();
                                        Log.i("User Name ", "FbName : "+user.getName());
                                        Log.i("User Id ", "FbId : "+user.getId());
                                        Log.i("User Id ", "FbLocation : "+user.getLocation().toString());

                                        Log.i("User Id ", "FbEmailId : "+user.getLink());
                                        Log.i("User Id ", "FbDob : "+user.getBirthday());

                                        Log.i("User Id ", "FbGender : "+user.asMap().get("gender").toString());
                                        Log.i("User Id ", "FbEmail : "+user.getProperty("email").toString());
                                        //Log.i("User Id ", "FbCity : "+user.getLocation().getCity().toString());
                                        //Log.i("User Id ", "FbState : "+user.getLocation().getState().toString());
                                        Log.i("User Access Token ", "FbAccess Token : "+session.getAccessToken());

                                        Log.i("USER LIKES", "USER LIKES" + user.getLink().toString());

                                        String fqlQuery = "SELECT music, books, movies FROM user where uid ="+user.getId();
                                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                        bundle.putString("q", fqlQuery);
                                        Request request = new Request(session, "/fql", bundle, HttpMethod.GET, 
                                            new Request.Callback() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                    Log.i("INFO", response.toString());
                                                }
                                            });
                                        Request.executeBatchAsync(request);

                                        pBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                                        String name = user.getName();
                                        String dob = user.getBirthday();
                                        gender = user.asMap().get("gender").toString();

                                        if(gender.equalsIgnoreCase("male")){

                                            genMale.setChecked(true);
                                            //genFemale.setSelected(false);
                                            //Toast.makeText(context, "male", 0).show();
                                        }
                                        else{

                                            //genMale.setSelected(false);
                                            genFemale.setChecked(true);
                                            //Toast.makeText(context, "female", 0).show();

                                        }

                                        String email =user.getProperty("email").toString();
                                        String city = user.getLocation().getProperty("name").toString();
                                        String url="http://graph.facebook.com/"+user.getId()+"/picture?type=large";
                                        setText(name, dob, email, city, "","",url);

                                        userIdFB = user.getId();

                                        accessTokenFB = session.getAccessToken();

                                    }catch(Exception ex){
                                        ex.printStackTrace();
                                    }


                                }

                                else{
                                    pBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    Log.i("ELSE", "ELSE");
                                }
                            }


                        });
                        //session.getAccessToken();
                        //Toast.makeText(context, "Session AccessToken : "+session.getAccessToken(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    if(session.isClosed()){

                        //Toast.makeText(context, "Closed", 0).show();
                    }

                }


            });
```

So the problem is that what should I add in this so that I can get all the interests of my current logged in user.
Please help me to solve this any help would be appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Salman Khan I have one issue in i required your help in this. I was able to post text using the Facebook Request but every time it showing the **AUTHORIZATION DIALOG** even though i have authorized the  app. Could you please provide me any solution to this issue ..

Comment: What is the Version of your Facebook SDK ???

Comment: facebook-android-sdk-3.6.0

Comment: @SalmanKhan Are you getting location and birthday using getLocation and getBirthday?